# Chaining multiple for loops together into one

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two lists read from a file that look something along the lines of this:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
```

I then have a for loop that needs to call both of those lists:

```
res = []
for i in list1:
    for x in list2:
        if i + x * 2 == 10:
             res.append((i,x))
```

What I want to do is chain the for loops into one, so that it will only go through each number once, for example:

```
res = []
for i in list1 and x in list2:
    if i + x * 2 == 10:
        res.append((i,x))
```

Doing the above now, will output an error that `x` is not defined:

```
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> list2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
>>> res = []
>>> for i in list1 and x in list2:
...     if i + x * 2 == 10:
...         res.append((i,x))
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
>>>
```

How can I go about doing this pythonically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try <s>[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)</s> [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) :

```
import itertools
...
for i, x in itertools.product(list1, list2):
   if i + x * 2 == 10:
       res.append((i, x))
```

Comment: using zip, then the loop will only execute 5 times.   So only 5 pairs evaluated, but the original will evaluate 25 times.There should no solution for this. You can do using matrix by duplicate the list1, but what you will get from duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

What I do is use a `range` loop, i.e. looping over possible indices instead of elements. Of course, you'd have to make sure that the lists are the same length, but it is really helpful. Implemented in your situation:

```
res = []
for index in range (len (list1)):
    if list1 [index] + list2 [index] * 2 == 10: res.append ((list1 [index], list2 [index]))
```

And if I dare, a one-liner:

```
res = [(list1 [index], list2 [index]) for index in range (len (list1)) if list1 [index] + list2 [index] * 2 == 10]
```

Remember, this only cross-searches lists, and doesn't loop over list2 for every element in list1.

Comment: What if the lists are not the same length?

Comment: Well, I kinda assumed you wanted to check each respective element against each other (ie, 1st with 1st, etc.), But I suppose that isn't what you want. If you just want to check each for each (ie, check everything against the first, everything against the second, etc.), then you will need to use the code you already have. But by the sound of your question, which implies you want each number to be checked less often, it sounds like you want a cross-search (my answer).